Can we clarify the difference between excitation and ionization?
Especially in the context of spectroscopy, these terms often seem conflated. Let's take the auger effect for instance. EAG laboratories describes the process as involving the excitation of an atom by the creation of a core shell vacancy and relaxation by the filling of said vacancy, ultimately leading to the release of an auger electron. Maybe I am missing something here, but I would not describe the initial creation of a core shell vacancy as excitation. That would be ionization, no? Excitation would be raising an electron to a higher energy level.
Anyway, why are some people saying an atom is excited by the ejection of an electron when this is better described as ionization? Maybe the distinction isn't even important and I'm splitting hairs here?
Sources:
https://www.eag.com/techniques/spectroscopy/auger-electron-spectroscopy/

I expect ionisation is the process where a valence electron escapes from an atom whereas here, it is an inner shell electron that escapes. Perhaps its this difference that is being signalled by the use of the word "excitation".
To answer this fully would probably require a historian of spectroscopy and its termonology.
